# trouble using SFINAE for templated constructor

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03, c++98

What is the difference between the following 2:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<double, T>::value>::type>
explicit Approx(const T& value) {}
```

vs

```
template <typename T>
explicit Approx(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<double, T>::value, T>::type& value) {}
```

`Approx` is the constructor of a normal class (not templated) and I need types that `double` is constructible from

My problem is that the first one works, but is not C++98 (default template argument, etc. - I have my own c++98 traits for `enable_if` and `is_constructible`)

The reason I'm asking is because I want to support strong typedefs of `double`:

```
class Volatility {
    double underlying_;
public:
    explicit Volatility(double u) : underlying_(u) {}
    explicit operator double() const { return underlying_; }
};

Approx(Volatility(1.)); // error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C++03 version doesn't work because it can't deduce T, given the argument.  The usual C++03 mechanism for constructors is an extra default argument.

```
template<typename T>
explicit Approx(const T& value, typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<double, T>::value>::type* dummy = 0) {}
```

`T` is deducible in this form, and if `T` meets the expectations specified by `enable_if`, the extra argument ends up being `void*`.